# Answer accepted (and up-voted) but only 10 rep gained?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, accepted-answer

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220013/expectation-on-mock-object-doesnt-seem-to-be-met-moq/1220068#1220068) this morning, and shortly thereafter it was up-voted and accepted (presumably the up-vote came from the asker).

However, my rep has only increased by 10, rather than the expected 25 (up-vote + accepted answer). It has been 15 minutes since the answer was accepted ... is it a bug, or is the reputation boost from accepted answers on a timer nowadays?

**Edit:** This is the first and only up-vote/accepted answer I have had today, so it's not related to the daily reputation cap.

Comment: Same case here with one question. Rep shows 25 rep gained, but only 10 points increase... Rep graph shows that I surpased 70 rep, but only 69 is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you lost an entirely different accepted answer. Unfortunately there's no way to track or find that.

Comment: Ah you could be right! I should look through some of the candidates and see if that's the case. So having answers "unaccepted" doesn't show on the reputation tracker?

Comment: No it doesn't show in reputation or history although it's been requested http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it seems like the only explanation (despite it being a heck a of a coincidence!).

Answer (score 2):

[Your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top) and [Jon's tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=615&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today&showzero=true) both show you as earning 25 points for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220013/1220068#1220068).

Comment: You're right - my "recent activity" page does say 25 points, yet my rep only increased from 20,950 to 20,960. Unless it's some sort of caching issue at my end.

Comment: +1 for spotting that, by the way, even though it doesn't explain the discrepancy in rep gain.