# Reputation notification of deselected answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, accepted-answer, notifications

This was never an issue before, but now I notice it now that I have many answers accepted as the "accepted answer".  We receive +15 rep for an acceptance.  We receive notification in our reputation tab about "acc +15". However, when someone de-selects the answer, our rep decreases accordingly, but we never receive any notification on which question changed.  I just wanted to know which question changed is all. Am I not seeing this somewhere or does this not exist yet?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [implemented last night](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer/107007#107007), you'll now see unaccepts in your reputation history (in the user profile).

Comment: Can you see exactly what answer was unselected?

Comment: @Macro - you get a link to the answer (unless it was totally deleted along with the question, in which case you see the title but not a link...unless you have 10k rep and can see it).

Answer (score 3):

I think it makes sense that you don't get notification because the deselection is actually wiping out the vote record in the DB.

Comment: Why the downvote on this one? This is a good technical reason if true. Is it not true?

Comment: LOL, this is the second time I've gotten a random downvote on a factually correct answer.

Comment: Implementation should follow specifications, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't see it.  You don't see any notification for revocation of upvotes or downvotes either.  If the notification was in the time window you've speficied, it simply vanishes.