# Notification when my answer is unaccepted?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, answers, reputation-summary

I just lost some reputation, presumably because someone changed their selected answer from mine to someone else's. Can these losses of reputation be noted on my reputation page similar to the other ways in which my reputation fluctuates? I'd like to figure out which answer was unaccepted so I can review it and possibly learn a thing or two.

I read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15912/reputation-notification-of-deselected-answer) covering the same topic, and I get that the vote record no longer exists in the database, but still isn't it possible to provide notification to the user of this vote change?

Comment: I assume you mean more than just the iPhone downvote? http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/153535?StartDate=2009-10-09&EndDate=2009-10-09&Tab=Reputation

Comment: Same happened to me at some point today, +1 for this

Comment: I could swear this is a dupe, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Jon: (hint) It's linked in the question. ;)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: He mentions the dupe question in the last sentence. He did want a little more explanation though. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15912/reputation-notification-of-deselected-answer

Comment: @Marc: Yes, more than the iPhone downvote; I find it very helpful to know when I've lost rep so I can improve my answers going forward; I would think losing an answered question to another answer would be the most helpful of these cases, but I can't figure out which answer of mine has been replaced.

Comment: Doh. I'm clearly too tired to do anything but just about breathe.

Comment: Quick everyone! Answer some C# questions while you have the chance!

Comment: Oh the irony... I've just had an answer unaccepted, and I don't know which one it was...

Comment: I know this is an old request, and that it's probably low priority, but I would very much appreciate a feature that gives this functionality. :-)

Comment: As of 2011-09-22 [you can see in your reputation report if an answer was unaccepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105309/how-do-you-want-to-be-notified-of-unaccepted-answers).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was [implemented last night](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer/107007#107007), you'll now see unaccepts in your reputation history (in the user profile).

Comment: I saw that recently! Any chance it might be broken? I just received -15 without a 'red-box' unaccept [in the reputation view](http://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe?tab=reputation).

Comment: i can't found anything why my scores get down in reputation area.

Answer (score 18):

It strikes me that the vote record being removed from the database makes rep recalcs fundamentally unreliable. For example, take a day when this happens:

- Answer accepted
- 100 upvotes
- Answer unaccepted

Total reputation: 185 (you hit the cap, then the 15 is removed)

After recalc: 200.

Basically a rep recalc is meant to replay history - but it can't do that if the history isn't there any more. A vote given and then removed is *not* the same as the vote never being cast. It seems to me there are three options:

1. Start recording *actual* vote history, rather than just votes which haven't been deleted
2. Change rep algorithm so that it wouldn't matter (which may not be feasible with *any* kind of limit - I'm not sure)
3. Ignore the problem

Personally I'd like the first option - although I see the major benefit as being things like this overall question, where a change has happened (losing 15 rep) but there is no data left to say *why* it happened.

Comment: Good answer for only being able to do much beyond breathing at the moment.

Comment: Now it seems that the "accepted" reputation bonus is not included in the 200 rep daily limit.

Comment: @Paŭlo: Yes, accepted answers and upvotes are now essentially entirely separate.

Answer (score 7):

The issue TheTXI was highlighting in that response is that the `/recent` page simply lists data in the "votes" table of the database.  Upvotes, downvotes, and accepts are all noted by a single record, these are accumulated and displayed in your `/recent` page.

However, when an answer is unaccepted, a record is actually being removed from the database.  The query which shows your `/recent` page has no way of knowing that a record used to exist, therefore it shows nothing.  Changing this would not only require adding database data when the accepted answer changes, but modifying the `/recent` page to acquire that data as well as the plain `votes` data.

Comment: If you think that you can just go and rewrite my answer and make it better and get an upvote from me, you'd be right.

Comment: @TheTXI: Think of the positive, you will not be downvoted for no reason for a correct answer on this question. ;)

Comment: I would presume, then, that the same issue applies when a person revokes a downvote/upvote, that a record is being pulled from the DB so there's no way to tell when, say, someone used to think my answer helpful but do not anymore. I would think this particular case would be the most helpful for people trying to improve on the answers that they give by seeing how they are bettered by others.

Comment: Couldn't the record be modified from accepted to accepted-but-revoked or some such? I'm not familiar with the DBs particulars, but that way there would be some lasting record of this kind of event. (The same could be done for un-up- and un-down-voting).

Comment: Nothing is impossible, it is just up to the SO team to choose which feature requests they choose to implement.  I am sure Database changes and additions are near the bottom of the priority list.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, this is the answer you've got unaccepted.

[how to upload file by POST in libcurl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510346/how-to-upload-file-by-post-in-libcurl)

And you can check the question timeline here, you got unaccepted at **2009, Oct 9 05:44** :-)

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1510346/timeline

[image]

Comment: Wow! And can you enlighten us how you worked that out? Brute force?

Comment: @Hendrik, Yes, above is just manual bruteforce. A bit lazy to write a script though, that could be done.

Comment: @Hendrik: Here is a very simple bookmarklet to see a timeline 
`javascript:(function() { var parts = location.href.split("questions/"); location = parts[0]+"posts/"+parts[1].split("/")[0]+"/timeline"})();`