# How can I see the rep lost due to removed accepted?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)

Why doesn't the reputation graph show the rep lost when someone removes the accepted answer to a question I've previously answered? Where else can I find this information?

Comment: IMHO, this isn't a dupe because this is a *support* question how this can be done (turns out it can't), rather than a *feature request* from someone who knows they can't and wants the feature added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2011-09-22 [you can see in your reputation report if an answer was unaccepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105309/how-do-you-want-to-be-notified-of-unaccepted-answers).

Original answer below the line.

---

You can't.  There isn't any feasible way.

You'd have to simply notice the absence of rep where you had it before, either on the reputation graph or on the recent rep page.

See Also:

- [Notification when my answer is unaccepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted) (feature-request)
- [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer) (feature-request)