# A reputation change does not show the reason of that

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification when my answer is unaccepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted)

In Stack Overflow when I put the mouse on my user name, I see the drop down menu with my reputation.
It mentions for today -15.
The problem is that there is no mention what is this for, e.g., if it is an answer down-vote, or an answer previously accepted marked as not accepted.
How can I see this?

Comment: A -15 most likely means that one of your previously accepted answers was unaccepted.

Comment: Shouldn't I know which one was unaccepted?

Comment: Oddly enough, this happened to me today as well...

Answer (score 4):

Click "reputation" for a breakdown of votes per day.

Direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/384706/user384706?tab=reputation

Comment: I did that.There is no mention there either.Perhaps is a small bug?

Comment: I think @squillman nailed it: unaccepted answer. It's not so much a downvote as a rollback, and therefore isn't shown.

Comment: So I shouldn't expect to see which one was unaccepted?

Comment: Exactly. See @ChrisF's link, it's pretty relevant.

Answer (score 3):

-15 denotes an unaccepted answer (or in very rare cases, a deleted/migrated question of yours which had 3 upvotes). As far now, you cannot trackback it in your reputation history. You can trackback it in the question's history, but the hard part is finding the question where this answer has been unaccepted. If you make a daily backup of your https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and parse it, then you should be able to find the missing +15 by yourself.

There's however a running feature request of being notified of unaccepted answers, which will undoubtely be implemented sooner or later: [How do you want to be notified of unaccepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105309/how-do-you-want-to-be-notified-of-unaccepted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot see it, if you don't remember which of your answers where previously accepted, and now they are not accepted anymore; the same it is true for up-voted posts.

For the questions, there is a page that reports when an answer has been accepted; for example, for this very question, there is https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/105553/timeline. If you have a suspect about which answer was accepted, and it is not accepted anymore, you can look the similar page of that question. There isn't a link for that page; you just take the canonical URL of a question, replace "questions" with "post," and replace the part after the question ID with "timeline."