# Why don't idle days show up, but a 0 rep day does show up?

Tags: discussion, reputation

As the title says, why does this 0 rep day show up in the screenshot? If a day has 0 rep, it was probably not very productive. So, why not classify it as idle and not show it like SO does for all idle days?

I have no idea why this shows up, I probably had some rep and then lost it. If that's true I'm not really interested to see that 0 rep day show up in between the days that did matter.

[image: Enhanced version with more freehand circles.]

Answer (score 5):

Your answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134530/correct-way-of-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-value) was [accepted on 21 August, but unaccepted again 9 seconds later](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7134530/timeline). (It was accepted yet again a day later.) I guess this is the reason for the 0 rep showing up for 21 August on your reputation report. Of course it would make more sense if the whole thing just wouldn't show up if there's no link you can follow. And judging by [Nick Craver's comment of 22 September here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105309/how-do-you-want-to-be-notified-of-unaccepted-answers/105314#comment-274946), I'd say this is a bug.

Comment: Although a zero does provide more information; it shows the presence of voting activity.

Comment: but the eventual accept that *did* matter was a day after. that accept is listed under August 22 where I'd expect it to be if I need to dig deeper into it. I have no use for a 0 rep the day before for an unaccept that was accepted later. it doesn't tell me anything useful.

Comment: @Robert: That information is just useless if there's no _link_ to the voting activity. (Unless you're willing to check a few timelines whenever you get the 0 rep.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt Agreed! It should either not show that day if it's not going to provide useful info, or show the +15/-15.

Answer (score 3):

Useful information can be contained in a net of 0 rep.  Here's an example:

[image]

Displaying a rep gain of 0 when nothing except an accept and unaccept is not particularly useful, but it is informational.  This would be much improved if "+15 accepted" and "-15 unaccepted" were shown, instead of nothing at all.

This list shows actions taken by other users towards your account which affect your reputation at any time.  It doesn't need to be limited to a rep counter.

Answer (score 1):

I see when something you posted gets approved or voted up, then a 0 rep will added to your list.

---

in case you self accept your post, you earn **0 rep**

Comment: What? If something get's approved or voted up, he'd get rep for it.

Comment: for example see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807493/how-can-i-inspect-the-data-sent-from-the-pandora-web-player/6919629#6919629 and he gets 0 rep for it

Comment: No. He gets 15 rep for it. [You might want to read the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: @PaddedCell In the example made by wtayyeb, the user who asked the question accepted his own answer; in that case, he doesn't get 15 points, nor 2 points.

Comment: see the first 0 rep in his rep list http://stackoverflow.com/users/64301/instanceoftom?tab=reputation and then tell me to where it is linked??

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Ohhh...good catch. Thank you! I completely missed that it was a self-answer.

Comment: @wtayyeb: That's a self-accept, which doesn't give any reputation.