# Reputation history on "my profile" page shows 0 for some days

Tags: discussion, reputation-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't idle days show up, but a 0 rep day does show up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107837/why-dont-idle-days-show-up-but-a-0-rep-day-does-show-up)

I just checked my reputation history page in "My profile" and for some days, it shows 0 reputation gained/lost without any further descriptions.

Given below screenshot for reference -

[image]

I know this means on that day my reputation score had some changes, maybe some acceptance and some downvote on other post whose NET result was zero. But those posts are not showing up when the div is expanded. I feel, when there are no posts to show in the expanded div, the div can also be hidden. Or if this has some other meaning please let me know.

Comment: If it was an acceptance and a down-vote those would appear as separate lines. It's more likely to be a reversed vote (i.e. someone voted on one of your posts and then changed their mind).

Comment: If you do a rep re-calc does it go away?

Comment: I'd always assumed that was a day when you visited the site but (shock, horror!) failed to gain or lose _any_ reputation.

Comment: @ChrisF - But if it was a reversed vote, then it should not appear in my list since it ideally means I did not get any upvote/downvote on that day. Or does the reputation history even records any action on voting?

Comment: @SachinShanbhag - I'm not sure. All I know is that it won't be two different things cancelling each other out.