# My reputation doesn't show when an accepted answer I wrote was unaccepted

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-history, unaccepted-answer

Basing on [How do you want to be notified of unaccepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105309/how-do-you-want-to-be-notified-of-unaccepted-answers) I should see on my reputation page when an answer I wrote is accepted, and then unaccepted. On Drupal Answers, this doesn't happen to me.

That is what happens for [How to run code on every page request - after modules are loaded?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35571/how-to-run-code-on-every-page-request-after-modules-are-loaded)

[image: screenshot]

The answer I wrote was unaccepted almost 3 hours after it was accepted; still I don't see anything in my reputation that shows that change.

This doesn't happen, when an accepted answer of mine is unaccepted, and accepted again in the same day (not even when that happens in a minute).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the accept and unaccept occur on the same day, they are hidden. The unaccept only shows in your history if it occurs on a different day than when it was originally accepted.

Nick Craver explains this in [not as straight-forward words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125137).