# How come I got only +29 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I just downvoted a very unclear question, got +4 for answers and one answer was accepted. That's all the rep change for today, so far. So, I expected to get +44. However, I only got +29. What could have happened?

`/reputation` says:

```
 3   5856295 (-1)
 2   5856883 (10)
 2   5854614 (10)
 2   5856883 (10)
 1   5856883 (15)
-- 2011-05-02 rep +44   = 25615     

** rep today: 44
```

But the tab at the top of the main screen keeps saying +29...

Comment: Check `/reputation`, and post the information for today here if you still don't understand what happened.

Comment: @Cody Gray: done. I don't understand this at all.

Comment: I guess alex' (now deleted) answer gave the right clue: It seems that _one_ of your answer was unaccepted. EDIT: See also [this related answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted/89123#89123).

Comment: @Hendrik: yes, an answer having been unaccepted seems probable, that's happened to me before. Too bad I don't get notified when that happens. Is there a way to find out which answer that was?

Comment: Yes, see that related answer: Check the timeline of all your answers and see which one was unaccepted. Seems feasible since you're a command line junkie. When you have a script, let me know `:-)` (When I tried, I ran into the trouble that `lynx -source 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/166749/larsmans#qpage_1-anpage_30-qsort_votes-ansort_votes'` gives me the _first 30_ answers ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836570/installing-jython-ubuntu/5836609#5836609) got unaccepted on following question today (which is -15)

[Installing Jython on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5836570)

Please take a look on [question's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5836570/timeline) for that

[image]

Comment: [Again brute force???](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted/89123#89123)

Comment: @Hendrik still brute-force, and wrongly tried with data explorer query this time to find all of his accepted answers (which took time), but the question wasn't there since it is posted 2 days ago.

Comment: I guess the only way you're able to do this brute force is because people haven't answered that many questions? I just lost 15 rep points, and thought I'd check to see which answer to got unaccepted. But given [the number of answers I've given](http://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray), I'm not sure that's reasonable. (Edit: Hmm, and now I just got those 15 points back. Oh well.)