# Negative rep in activity mouseover despite positive rep?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

What's up?

[image: rep mouseover]

UPDATE: Seems the *timeline* feature described by @YOU is useful so I made a bookmarklet:

`javascript:(function() { var parts = location.href.split("questions/"); location = parts[0]+"posts/"+parts[1].split("/")[0]+"/timeline";})();`

Comment: If and when [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted) will get implemented, things like this will become much clearer. :-)

Comment: Ah - a feature request from 2009. I will wait with bated breath :(

Comment: No worry one year requests have recently been completed - once they realize it's a good request they will do this one as well. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because <s>two</s> one of your other answers got unaccepted today (which is <s>-30</s> -15). <s>One of them</s> which is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866862/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-row-jquery)

You can check details on [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5866862/timeline) of that question.

[image]

**Edit**: I originally thought you have got two unaccepted answer today, but according to question in your screenshot - [javascript : closing the window on a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791931/javascript-closing-the-window-on-a-button-click/5792071#5792071), your answer was accepted **yesterday**, so there is no +15 gain for today. You only lose one accepted answer today, which cause -15 in your today reputation, that's all.

Comment: Hmm - how annoying - thanks - how did you see that at a glance?

Comment: @mpl YOU is a mage don't you know that? :p

Comment: Ok @Sha - how would **I** do that

Comment: if @YOU is using a query he can share it, otherwise it's mystery to me as well..

Comment: @Shadow, it's a brute-force searching on his non accepted answers, I have idea to write a script but yesterday I got suspended temporarily because of crawling on another case, I need to do such things carefully :D

Comment: @YOU suspended from [data](http://data.stackexchange.com/)? Anyway, how can you tell specific answer (that is now not accepted) was previously accepted?

Comment: @Shadow, nope, from Stack Overflow... Regarding unaccepted see timeline - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5866862/timeline

Comment: @YOU wow, forgot about the nifty `/timeline`!

Comment: Here is a bookmarklet I just made `javascript:(function() { var parts = location.href.split("questions/"); location = parts[0]+"posts/"+parts[1].split("/")[0]+"/timeline";})();`