# Unaccepting an answer doesn't show up in the reputation stats?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)

Yesterday, I lost 15 points. But I couldn't find where it came from. I think someone has unaccepted my answer again. The quick stats view in the top says `-15 today`. But there is no reference to where it came from.

It seems logical that it doesn't say: `-15 for answer foo`. But shouldn't there be `0 for answer foo`?
I don't know if it is a bug or a feature request, but I would like to mention it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer), [Notification when my answer is unaccepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a user notification could be given in your inbox.

> Your accepted answer has been unpromoted. Your reputation has been adjusted in consequence

Comment: Maybe in your inbox is a bit too much, but maybe in the quick view when you hover over your name? Just like the +10, but then with: 0: unaccepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, you answer have been unaccepted on this question

[Make overlay background click-through-able](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822234/make-overlay-background-click-through-able)

according to question timeline

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4822234/timeline

Comment: How did you find this? Just on post? Did you look through all my answers? Can I do this by user? =)