# Add unaccept to reputation history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accepted-answer, reputation-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)

I lost 15 rep today on SU which, so far, has been all I've been able to accomplish there today.  -15 shows up under total rep for the day so I figured that someone moved their acceptance from one of my answers to another, or just flat out unaccepted mine.  I went into my rep history and there's no trace of it.  I'd like to know which answer of my was unaccepted.  Could we please add this as an event in the rep history?

(or, maybe I'm completely ignorant and am just missing it)

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted

Comment: Ah, surely enough a dupe.  The age of that question is not promising for getting this implemented...

Comment: And it's implemented :)