# Why didn't I get notified when I got unaccepted?

Tags: support, reputation, notifications

I got unaccepted for some question (I know this as I had 1360 rep yesterday night, and now I have 1345). According to [Notification when my answer is unaccepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted) I should've been notified, but I didn't. I searched through most of my history, and yet I can still not find it.

Why is this?

Comment: It should be visible in your reputation history, as stated in the question you link. There is no explicit notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it happened in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16870281/447356), see its [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16870281/timeline):

> [image]

Nick said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107007/152859):

> Starting with the next build, this will show in your reputation history, shown as a -15 on the day it occurs (**except if it's re-accepted in the same day**)

So apparently it's two-way, meaning that if it was accepted then unaccepted in the same day you won't see it in the reputation history. Not sure if it's a bug or not but your case is proof enough it does happen.

Comment: could you tell me where things like ___timeline___ are described ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя nowhere officially, many times users just find it randomly. Unofficial place holding many of those features is this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not supposed to create an inbox notification.

They are, however, recorded on your reputation page for the day.

What I suspect did happen, however is that someone accepted then immediately unaccepted an answer. You will not see this removal reflected on the top bar, but at the same time since the time between the accept/unaccept was short either of these will not be recorded in the history.

Comment: Hmm.. [nearly 16 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182670/152859) are short time? :-)

Comment: I never thought they were - as mentioned I went over my rep history finding it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - OK. Not sure what is going on then. Could be that it is "in the same day".

Comment: Might be a bug, really can't tell... maybe best to ask Nick how it *should* behave then we'll all be smarter? :)