# Is there any way to find out which of my answers got unaccepted?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation notification of deselected answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15912/reputation-notification-of-deselected-answer)

I keep logging into SU every couple of hours or so, and just now when I logged in, I noticed that there was a drop in my rep - the amount being 15 points indicates that an answer of mine was unaccepted. Is there a way I can find out which answer was unaccepted? More than rep loss, I'm more interested in knowing the unaccepted answer so that I can post my (future) answers better and at the same time learn from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way of doing it. Your best bet is to either remember the question you got the accepted answer on or simply search through the answers you've given, maybe one of them rings a bell.

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really want to know you can look at the last data dump, dump all your answers that are accepted, then go look and see which aren't accepted anymore.