# Loss of reputation when answer unaccepted

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Today I anwsered a question [Loopback/Localhost Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508942/loopback-localhost-question/7509161#7509161). My answer didn't get accepted, no biggy the question got answered and person who asked it was happy. However my day's reputation (on Stack Overflow) now says +10 when it should be +25.

```
10 today 
+15 2 hours ago accept IE vs Chrome certificate handling, and SSL communication on XP vs Windows 7
+10 5 hours ago upvote Loopback/Localhost Question
-15 6 hours ago unaccept Loopback/Localhost Question
```

The question was only asked today, I posted my answer today and the question was marked as answered today so I don't think this is a side effect of the question being added to a previous day's reputation then being substracted from today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep there was a bug here for a timing/day edge case...it's now been fixed, you won't see that unaccept which was a quick accept/unaccept with no net change.

Answer (score 1):

If that is all the reputation change you have, then it is correct.
You had a reputation increase of 25 points for an accepted and an up-voted answer; take off 15 points for the answer that is not marked accepted anymore. The difference is 10 points.

**Edit:** It's a bug if the answer was accepted, and then marked as non accepted, on the same day basing on the UTC timezone; in that case, the reputation history should eventually report a +15 for the accepted answer, and a −15 for the answer being not accepted anymore. It could make sense to report both those changes because you could have already notice the +15 change, and then you would wonder why you don't see anymore the +15 you saw before.
The answer I gave before assumed that you were saying that the question was asked (and answered) in the same day basing on your timezone, which could mean a different day basing on the UTC timezone.

Comment: @NickCraver I'm not sure this is right -- The accept / unaccept happened on the same day, so that is a net of +0 for the day, show you either need to show both the accept and the unaccept or neither one. The accept that is listed is for a _different question_, only an unaccept is shown for the "Loopback/Localhost" question. His rep for the day should be +25.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Do you mean it is a bug or it is working as designed. I have an upvote (+10 on affected answer) and an accept (+15 for a different answer). I assume I should have an +15 accept and -15 unaccept for the anwser in question but only the -15 seems to be calculated resulting in 10+15-15 = 10 when it should be 10+15+15-15 = 25 right? or am I just going crazy.

Comment: @agf - You're right...there's a bug in the query for this specific case, deploying a fix momentarily.

Comment: @BernieWhite - See Nick's comment, you're not crazy.

Comment: @agf Thank you for checking that.

Comment: @BernieWhite You are correct; I thought that when you said that the answer was given in the same day the question was asked, you were referring to the day basing on your timezone. SE sites define a day basing on the UTC timezone.

Comment: Re: the edit - we don't show this because it's noise...potentially a *lot* of noise, as you can accept/unaccept/accept/unaccept....etc. and spam someone's reputation page at will by doing so.  Also, this happens naturally with new users learning how accept works (I saw tons of examples when trying to determine how best to represent that case).  In the end, I chose to only show a delta, if there was one...so accept/unaccept (even amounts on the same post) cancel out.  If there are an odd number and it was a net change for the day, we'll show it.

Comment: @NickCraver I see your point, and I agree. I was thinking more of the case where (for example) an answer is accepted, and nine hours later the accepted answer is changed. To do that, and avoid the cases you reported, the code should consider different cases, such ("A" means accepted answer, "NA" means the answer has been marked as non accepted): A NA (show both), A NA A (show it has been accepted), A NA A NA (show the first two), A NA A NA A (show it has been accepted). I am not sure it's worth implementing such code.