# Inconsistency in accounts reputation summaries

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Reputation display bug… Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again)

On Apr 17, I got a couple of upvotes on a [question and answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61094/any-way-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-typing-of-the-dead-or-how-to-type-a) posted to Gaming SE, as seen on my [reputation history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/23240/ben-lee?tab=reputation) on that site (sorted by time):

[image: Gaming reputation history]

I answered the question myself, and on Apr 17 someone upvoted both the question and answer at the same time, which is what the circled +5 and +10 corresponds to. As you can see, this screenshot shows my entire history on the site, and shows the correctly total reputation of 151 (I added it up to confirm).

My [SE accounts list](https://stackexchange.com/users/222388/ben-lee?tab=accounts) agrees:

[image: SE accounts summary]

And so does my [accounts summary on Gaming SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/23240/ben-lee#user-panel-accounts):

[image: Gaming SE accounts summary]

The inconsistency is in the accounts summary of every other SE site besides Gaming. For example, here's what my [accounts summary on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480943/ben-lee#user-panel-accounts) shows:

[image: SO accounts summary]

All my other non-Gaming sites on the network also show "146" here. I didn't do a careful examination, but from a quick examination, it appears like this is the only inconsistency (the other accounts are shown with the correct reps on all sites).

I thought at first that this might just be caching (even though 2 days is kind of a long time for a cache of this sort). But if that were the case I would expect the stale cache to show "136" (assuming a relatively naive caching strategy), since I got 15 points within seconds of each other on Apr 15, and I had 136 rep before that. So the fact that it shows "146" leads me to believe it may be indicative of some other problem. Or even if it is just a stale cache (showing 146 because question rep and answer rep are refreshed differently?), two days seems to be a long time to cache this. Furthermore, the inconsistency only exists in some places, not others.

Comment: It's caching, it's always caching.

Comment: `[status-caching]`

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast, Hmm, even for two days? If it's caching, that seems almost like a cache-refresh bug then.

Comment: @BenLee 4 days would be my (educated) guess. Now stop checking out your rep, it'll sync in a couple of days...

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast, I only noticed this by accident, not like I was actively checking out my rep :). By yeah, i'll give it a few days and come back if it's still inconsistent.

Comment: @BenLee Wasn't accusing you, but I know how hard it is to stop checking it out once you first notice that there's something not entirely correct in there... It's how they keep us addicted ;)

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast, and for the record, it's not *always* caching, as my very first question on meta indicates: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107027/when-someone-unaccepts-your-answer-after-initially-accepting-it-it-looks-like-t (another reputation display bug there, turned out to actually be a bug)

Comment: @BenLee Caching being the answer to all bugs, and 6 to 8 weeks the answer to all feature requests is a MSO meme... ;) It just happens that this time it's (probably) the correct answer too.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast, approching 5 days and the problem is still there -- still think it's caching?

Comment: I think it's time for a bounty. My money is on it's an actual bug. After all, cache invalidation is one of the only two hard things in computer science, right? ;) http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html

Comment: @Ben - There's a difference between simple caching (which fixes itself) and network-level denormalization that can get out of sync :)

Comment: @NickCraver, wouldn't an out-of-sync network-level denormalization (that doesn't fix itself) be considered a bug? I would consider it so anyway.

Comment: Honestly, I really don't understand the all the down votes here. How is this not a legitimate bug? It's been 6 days, and the cache has not been invalidated. That sounds like something went wrong, not just like a normal cache TTL.

Comment: @BenLee - ...because it's not a simple cache, far *far* from it, and the downvotes are probably because this is a dupe of over a dozen other meta reports.

Comment: As @NickCraver said, this has happened before. When I had a related problem, the official response was *Our network-level user cache had a hiccup.* See: [10 rep missing intermittently from account overview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121716/10-rep-missing-intermittently-from-account-overview)