# Reputation count mismatch at multiple site

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different reputation in my profile page, is it a bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114485/different-reputation-in-my-profile-page-is-it-a-bug)
>   [Inconsistency in accounts reputation summaries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129800/inconsistency-in-accounts-reputation-summaries)

I can see mismatch of reputation count of stackoverflow and gaming SE on different SE sites. Not that I care for the small amount of reputation, but I thought I should report it. I was witnessing it for more than a week, I thought it might be a cache issue and would be solved at next recalc, but it's still there.

Here are the screenshots taken at different Stack sites

**GameDev**
[image: Game Development]

**StackOverflow**
[image: StackOverflow]

**Global StackExchange**
[image: SE]

**Gaming SE aka Arqade**
[image: Arqade]

Comment: I know I've seen this bug in another question, but I can't find it. When this happened to me, a manual recalc fixed the glitch.

Comment: See also [Different reputation in my profile page, is it a bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114485/140449)

Comment: In the second question it was a caching issue, but I am facing this bug since last week and on different browser.

Comment: The caching is *server-side*.  It's not live information.

Comment: Even if it's something from server-side, it's still a bug to show wrong information on a live sit. In the possible duplicate it was answered that it takes an hour to get it fixed, it's not fixed yet, even after a week.