# Is the Unaccept Notification broken?

Tags: bug, reputation, accepted-answer, notifications

According to

- [Notification when my answer is unaccepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/notification-when-my-answer-is-unaccepted) <sup>**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FetCp.png)**</sup>

Unaccepts should show up in your reputation history. I do remember seeing those notifications for a brief few months in the past, but not for a long time now (it *is* a rare occurence, so I have to wait for it to happen...).

Just now, I got greeted with another one of these mystery rep transactions:

[image]

Question:

#### Is this feature broken, or is something else at play?

*Could it be that it has to do with the new (black) site banner/header/menu thing? It seems to me that the notification system in general is kinda broken/quirky since then. E.g. I seem to get the same notifications at least 3 or four times, sometimes unable to clear them at all, except by clicking on the "colored tab" notification counts in the profile page. I don't really mind that, but it might point at an issue?*

---

<sup>**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FetCp.png)**</sup> and also
 * [How do you want to be notified of unaccepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105309/how-do-you-want-to-be-notified-of-unaccepted-answers)
 * [Reputation notification of deselected answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15912/reputation-notification-of-deselected-answer) etc...

Comment: Any action that is undone in the same day will not show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any vote or accept that is undone in the same day will not show up in the reputation view. However, the blue icon only shows the difference from the last time you clicked on the tab.

So if:

1. Someone accepts your answer.
2. You click on the tab and see the accept.
3. The person unaccepts the answer in the same day.

The next time you return to your profile, you will see the -15. But when you click on the tab, you will not see any indicator. Same applies to votes.

I believe the behavior of the reputation tab is independent of the banner/header/menu thing.

Comment: Bummer. That means I can't know what was unaccepted. I don't recall seeing an accept earlier today (I might have dismissed it with the phone app?). (_Also, I agree the profile/rep tab is likely independent, but at least dismissing the 'change' markers in profile view appears to fail to update the global inbox thing. That used to be better (by a big margin) in the past :(_)

Comment: True @sehe, unaccepting in same day is making it vanish into thin air as if the accept never occurred in the first place. You can try and check your Achievements box in top bar, go to all the +15 events you see there and hopefully catch the one that isn't really accepted but good chance it's also deleted from that box.