# Show other accepted answers in Recent Activity

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer, recent-activity

I can find similar requests to this, but nothing quite the same.

Basically, I'd like to know (via Recent Activity) if a question that I answered gets an Accepted Answer that wasn't mine. This is something that currently doesn't appear to be easy to identify apart from adding it as a favourite and manually checking whether the Answers box changes colour. I could use this for situations where I answer a question to the best of my knowledge, but remain curious as to whether someone has a better way (albeit according to the questioner) or whether something has been resolved satisfactorily.

Edit : As Adam says, this could be extended to show activity in any question participated in. If that was the case, I think it should be user-configurable, eg

1. "Show Accepted Answers to Parcipated Questions : Yes/No" default : yes
2. "Show Answers to Participated Questions : Yes/No" default : no. Yes to this implies yes to the previous question.
3. "Show Comments to Parcipated Questions  : Yes/No" default : no

Comment: Sort of related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer

Answer (score 8):

I think this could go under the broader category of "Show activity that happens to any question I participate in" which would include new answers, and possibly new comments.

This would also give you what you need, and more - being able to see other answers that come in after yours may also teach you something new about the subject.

So yes, I would also like to see this feature, but in a more expanded form.

Comment: I wondered about this. It might be overkill for the more active users, so perhaps it should be a user-specific setting.

Comment: +1. I would like this functionality the be on a separate tab, though.