# Notification when someone else's answer is accepted

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, notifications

I would like to know when someone else's answer is accepted on a question that I have also provided an answer for.  I'd like to know how someone else better solved a problem so that I can evaluate that solution against mine and learn some things.  Sure I could click through my list of answers, but the timing of when answers are accepted makes that unfeasible the larger your answer list gets.

This can help learn something about the question topic, but also can provide me an example of how to provide a better formed answer than what I submitted.

Comment: Dupe of [Show other accepted answers in Recent Activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30363/show-other-accepted-answers-in-recent-activity)?

Comment: I think it make sense, but I think you should be able to subscribe to activity in a question, make it optional, so you dont get too much info you dont really want

Comment: I agree, if this is done it should be optional I don't need that noise.

Answer (score 13):

If this ever does get implemented, please make it an opt-in feature.  When I was most active on Stack Overflow I'd be submitting 10, even 20 answers a day on some days, and even though I tended to get something like 60-70% of them accepted, being notified about every question I *didn't* get the accept on would have been a huge amount of noise.

I can see why some people would be interested in this and I don't have anything against the request, but I do wish to state for the record that many of us don't really care if our answers are the accepted ones and don't want to get spammed with half a dozen new notifications every day like what happened with the favorites.

Comment: +1 or when OPs go yo-yo and accept, un-accept, accept, un-accept, change accept... I see enough noise with that in my reputation when I'm the one whose answer is getting accepted/unaccepted. I don't want to see it for every single answer even I'm not one of the yo-yo victims.

Answer (score 9):

How about informing me about an accept when I favourite a question? If that's not already happening. It would make a lot of sense anyway.

That way, it's optional, yet it doesn't add another option to the UI.

Comment: This could be a workable solution. If this has already been implemented I wouldn't know since all my favs were answered b4 I even signed up. I use my favorites as a long-term repository of interesting (or amusing) threads. I see this feature as something for short-term monitoring (i.e., until the question is answered) I guess I would have to un-fav it after the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of being notified when someone else’s answer is accepted. In fact, I found *this* year old feature-request while looking for a similar feature. I just posted an answer to a question with a bounty on it and I would like to see how it turns out.

There are often occasions where I’m interested in the outcome of a particular thread, but I don’t want to add it to my favorites (which I use as a long-term resource). It would be nice to be able to "subscribe to activity in a question", as @bangoker put it.

I think it would be useful to have a checkbox, or something on each thread that allows you to be notified — in your profile — when a question has been answered, regardless of who answered it. That way you could opt-in on a per-thread basis.

One thing I’d like to stress is that I do NOT want to be notified by email (like some forums do). I don’t know about anyone else, but my SO profile page is my home page to the whole SE network and I check it *far* more frequently than I check my email.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to any notifications that happen, we should find a way to indicate that in the answers list on the profile.  Right now if I'm looking at my answers I see the ones that were accepted, and for anything else I have to click through to find out what happened.  It'd be helpful to have a visual indicator for "an answer was accepted but it wasn't yours", so that I'd know it's been resolved.  (I try to revisit questions I participated in that didn't get an answer to see if I can help further.)