# Notify me when an answer is accepted, even if it's not mine

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification when someone else's answer is accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62600/notification-when-someone-elses-answer-is-accepted)

I would like to be notified if the OP accepts an answer to a question I've answered, even if the accepted answer is not my answer.
Why? I would like to understand why the accepted answer is better than mine so I can learn something about the question itself — and probably about answering, too.
Does this make sense?