# Notify us when answer of someone else's to a question get accepted to which we have given an answer

Tags: feature-request, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification when someone else's answer is accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62600/notification-when-someone-elses-answer-is-accepted)

I would like to raise a feature request for notifying the user who has given an answer to a question, and someone else's answer has been accepted which was posted later.

#### The reasons behind requesting this ?

Giving a answer to a question means the answerer knows about what the quesiton is about, and/or has done some research to answer it. When some other answer to the same question gets accepted, I as a user should get the notification so that I could go back and check what was the exact answer to the question. This would also enhance my understanding about that particular language about which the question is asked. It could be more or less same answer as that of mine, but could be more efficient, more readable or one-liner(many time :)) .

#### For example:

I am a beginner in PHP, I ask questions and also post answers to question which I find easy for myself. With such kind of notification I could go back and check the accepted answer and gain more knowledge about that particular domain/concern/question.

Comment: Ok, I see that asked 2 year's ago. What to infer from it? It does not have any final comment? No moderator-tag?

Comment: It means that it's been forgotten about. Bumping it would bring it back to people's attention.