# Show accepted answers (not by you) in different highlight

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

This question is similar to [Show other accepted answers in Recent Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30363) but not exactly the same, so I will pose it.

When looking at a user's summary page under stats > Answers, each question has a votes tallied box next to the name of the question.  Currently, if your answer is not accepted, the vote box is gray.  If your answer *is* accepted, the vote box is green and the count is yellow.  The idea is to highlight questions where someone else's answer became accepted, so you can quickly see if someone had a better idea than you.  For instance, color the vote box dark gray or some other neutral but slightly negative color.

I believe this to be beneficial for newer users (such as myself) to encourage participation and potentially improve quality of answers.  Additionally, there are at least a few questions that I've answered with (in my opinion) the currently best available answer, but there have been no votes at all.  Some of these are old posts, and the OP may not have seen this old question (or simply don't care anymore).  I can't change the fact that the OP has not selected an answer, but at least I can tell if that's because the OP doesn't know better/has not logged in, or has found a better alternative answer.

If privacy is a concern, it can be made to display only on the currently logged in user's profile page.

Comment: The problem with this is that your answer not being accepted doesn't necessitate your answer being worse than another user's answer - ultimately, answers are whatever worked for the user. If your answer had a lot of great theory, but wasn't feasible for the user to implement, they may choose a different one as their selected answer.

Comment: Related: [Can we have a third color state for “accepted, by other answer than mine” in the stats tab?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88869/160003)

Comment: I'd really like to have this too, for the same reasons. I wonder if someone could answer whether or not this is feasible. It seems to be impossible with a common search (like `user:me is:answer isaccepted:1`) which may indicate that this could be harder than it seems.

Answer (score 3):

This is a me-too "answer" with an image of how it might look.  I didn't know any other way of posting the image.  @D.N. if you want to edit the image into your question I'll delete the answer.

The first one in the below image with the green outline shows that another user's answer has been accepted.

[image]