# Can we have a third color state for "accepted, by other answer than mine" in the stats tab?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Personally, I'd love to have a third color state for "accepted, by other answer than mine" in the stats tab.

This would allow users to see at the first glance, whether an answer does, or does not have an accepted answer already, so they wouldn't have to step into answers of type `answer-votes default` anymore, just to see whether the question was already answered.

What do you think?

Comment: I've added a example of one possible markup here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112710/152851

Answer (score 2):

I believe Accepted Answers ***are*** highlighted... Of course that won't tell you if it was *your* answer but you have reputation counter in the top. When you put your mouse cursor over it, some nice pop-up will be shown... From that you can see if it is your answer that was accepted - you get 15, 25, ... points for it.

Basically, I believe another color is not needed.

BTW. There is probably some way to do Greasemonkey script which would actually do what you ask for.

Comment: No, only your answers that were accepted are highlighted and the pop-up is just "the total number of votes". I think he means the stats tab on the user page, e.g. [on yours](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156075/pawel-dyda) you can see that you have the accepted answer for the self promotion question but you can't tell the difference between the cancel votes question where there is no accepted answer and the refactor question where there is an accepted answer but it's not yours.

Comment: Oh, I see. I somehow managed to omit "in the stats tab".

Comment: The reputation pointer doesn't give me an overview, since it only contains the last 3 (?) rep activities and doesn't help in skimming thru the answer list in the stats tab to see what question was already accepted. And I've never seen a highlighted answer that wasn't my own in my SO profile so far. Since I'm new to SE it's possible that I may just have missed something. Or there's a heavy delay in stats updates, but I don't really believe this.

Comment: @Rup: yes, that's what I meant (sorry, I'm not a native speaker). Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Jürgen: You are right, there is no highlight for this kind of answers in the stats tab. I thought you meant front page/tag page. Still, there is probably a way to do that with additional JavaScript.

Comment: @Paweł Dyda: Yeah, for SE users that are programmers themselves (me being one) a Greasemonkey script maybe would do, but what about all the non-programmers? Or programmers that don't know Javascript? Additionally, SE has about 30 different sites afaik. Not all of them are programming biased...