# Changing accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it poor form to switch accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers)

If I accept an answer and after sometime a new answer is posted. I think this new one would be my answer. So what can I do? Accept the new one or leave the acceptance with the old one?