# A question about stackoverlow etiquette

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it poor form to switch accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers)

Imagine that you've had a question answered by someone on stack overflow. The answer given was enough to get you going, so you mark the answer as accepted. A few minutes later, someone else answers your question but is more thorough in their answer and provides resources to help further the explanation. In short, it's a much better answer than the one that you previously accepted. Would it be considered bad form to choose the new answer as your accepted answer? Even though the previous answer was adequate, the new answer is much more helpful. Would that be enough to make you change your accepted answer?