# How should I treat the various answers to my question?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it poor form to switch accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers)

Once I accept an answer to my question, I don't think it's very polite to change the acceptance to another answer. Can I do something to recognize the other good answers besides just voting them up?

If I maintain a answer with a low score (because it's the first that I gave), what I can lose?

Should I change the answer to a locally written answer (cf. a link to another website) that is less complicated?

I'm asking about all this to make my [Math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73973/how-to-prove-e-isnt-a-frac-ab-not-irrationality-with-other-ways-or-ab) the best contribution it can be.

Will I be penalized for any of this? How does all this work?

Comment: I'd edit your question here to make it easier to understand, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: The truth it its several questions^^. But I would like to know what's the better way to proceed. Change or not change...that's the question.

Comment: Are you talking about using bounties to award existing answers or are you asking about the etiquette for answering your own question?

Comment: Not using bounty or about answer my own question, but about change the answer to another one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is a better answer, then you should unselect the current answer and select the better answer.  The person who had the first answer will lose their 15 points.  It might not feel great, but the person losing points is just losing points they probably shouldn't have had.

There is no penalty to do this.  *Maybe* some hurt feelings.

It might be wise to not accept an answer too soon in the future.