# Ability to see which accepted answer has been revoked

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, reputation-audit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)

I've been using SO now for about 6 months and I've had 2 or 3 occasions when I've noticed my rep has dropped by exactly 15. My only assumption is that somebody who previously accepted an answer from me has revoked it and (presumably) accepted a different answer.

I don't have a problem with people changing their minds nor do I have a problem with losing the rep if another answer is closer to what they need. My only frustration is I can't find a way to see which question so I can see what my answer was and what the new accepted answer is.

Sometimes I know an answer I give possibly isn't the best but it "works for me". Because of this it would be really useful if I could track when an answer I've given has been revoked, so I can go back to the question and perhaps learn something myself from whichever answer (presumably new) the OP has chosen to accept instead.

Comment: @balpha: OK so I hadn't spotted the earlier question despite checking for at least 15 minutes. So what do you suggest I do? The other question was asked nearly 2 years ago and it still hasn't been addressed despite the OP having had 109 upvotes. Is there any point in making feature requests at all? Or should I post that as a separate question?

Comment: Nagging about it by posting duplicate questions is certainly not the answer. If you accumulate enough rep, you could try setting a bounty on the original question.

Comment: @Cody: I wasn't nagging. I seriously spent 15 minutes looking through possible dupes but didn't spot that one. I've been using SO for 6 months and know about posting dupes (I have a rep of 4500+ over there and I vote to close obvious dupes myself when necessary). My response to balpha was probably knee-jerk but at least on SO we warn people of a dupe and it takes 5 votes to close. Also we don't point people at a dupe unless it has a satisfactory answer which 'Please show us when we lose an accepted answer' doesn't have...

Comment: Ah, I understand the confusion then. It still takes 5 regular users to close a question as a duplicate here. But on both sites, *moderators* can close questions immediately, and that's what happened here. And unfortunately, feature requests are just that: requests. There really isn't going to be a satisfactory answer, and it's best to keep all the discussion in one place.

Comment: ...to be honest I'd rather feature requests were addressed rather than be left open unanswered. I'll stick with SO itself and help people by answering questions there. As I said, I don't care about losing 15 rep here and there, it would just be useful to learn something from whomever posted the better answer than I did. Regards. :-)

Comment: You don't lose rep for having a question closed as a duplicate... Sorry you had a bad experience.

Comment: @Cody: I understand I don't lose rep on a closed question. My question was about getting notification as to which question has had its accepted answer changed (when my answer was originally accepted) - losing rep isn't an issue, it's just I only know it has happened when I see my rep drop and I'd like to see the better answer. BTW, setting a bounty on the original (linked) question has already been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like people change their mind a lot on Andriod Tag (out-of-date?) :-)

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4599520/timeline (2011, 1, 5)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4676056/timeline (2011, 1, 13)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4916512/timeline (2011, 2, 24)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5039044/timeline (2011, 2, 25)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5084629/timeline (2011, 2, 23)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5226818/timeline (2011, 3, 8)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5279492/timeline (2011, 3, 12)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5366432/timeline (2011, 3, 20)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5614812/timeline (2011, 4, 11)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4426325/timeline (2011, 4, 15)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5861335/timeline (2011, 5, 2)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5940456/timeline (2011, 5, 12)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5944275/timeline (2011, 5, 10)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5984548/timeline (2011, 5, 12)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6146365/timeline (2011, 5, 27)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6163745/timeline (2011, 5, 28)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6169294/timeline (2011, 5, 29)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6173827/timeline (2011, 5, 30)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5708641/timeline (2011, 5, 30)

Comment: "closed as exact duplicate 2 hours ago" ... "answered 9 minutes ago" Conclusion: you are magical.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, they're a fickle lot in the Android camp. I think I've worked out what you did there. Useful to know. :-)