# How can I view in history what owner of the question removed the 'accepted'-flag from my answer

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)

How can I view such event in the history?
I need to know, what answer should I change to improve the quality of it.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible but it would be useful.

Comment: This is not possible, but it has been asked before (multiple times). The earliest request is probably "[Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer)". I suggest you vote on that question to show your support, and delete your own question. Unless I misread your question and it is substantially different, in that case I suggest you edit your question to make the distinction more clear.

Comment: @Jan Fabry Thanks for the link, I didn't find it myself.